# Convert A String To A Variable in Coldfusion

Tags: string, coldfusion

I am using a cfloop to generate the titles of a bunch of variables.

Problem is on output I just get the actual variable name ie #qQuery.varName# instead of its value ie "Item Name".

Heres a quick taste of my code:

```
<cfloop query="qQuery">
<cfloop query="qTest">
<cfset varTest = "qQuery." & varName>
<cfoutput>#varTest#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<cfset vartest = qQuery[varName]>
```